# How do I convert a date column to a timestamp in a SQL select statement

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to write a DB2 query that is selecting a date column and I would like to convert it into a timestamp. For example, the query should take a column that is in a "mm/dd/yyyy" format and convert it to a column that is in a "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" format.

For example, if `END_DT` is a date column in the table, then I would like to select an an additional column that is `END_DT` but it also has a constant value of hh:mm:ss attached to it. I.e '1/29/2023' should be converted to '1/29/2023 11:22:33' (and so on, for each other END_DT value in each of returned row of the query).

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
    END_DT, TIMESTAMP(END_DT) AS end_dt_with_timestamp 
FROM <table>
```

but the `TIMESTAMP(END_DT)` portion of the query does not seem to work.

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?

Comment: There's a contradiction in your post. When you say "selecting a date column", this means, that this column doesn't have any format (dates are stored in a binary format)   like a string representation of date. So, please, edit your question with the corresponding CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements and the exact error message you get.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what platform and version of Db2 you are working with...

But see if your version of the `TIMESTAMP()` function supports two arguments, [with the second argument allowing for](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-timestamp)

> expression-2 must be an expression that returns a value of one of the
> following built-in data types: a time, a character string, or a
> graphic string. If expression-2 is a character or graphic string, its
> value must be a valid string representation of a time. For the valid
> formats of string representations of dates and times, see “String
> representations of datetime values” on page 75.

Thus all you need is

```
SELECT END_DT, TIMESTAMP(END_DT, '11:22:33') as end_dt_with_timestamp 
from <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `CONVERT` to change datatype to `DATETIME` and then `DATEADD` to add your specific timestamp.

Full code for your 1/29/2023 example:

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, 33, DATEADD(MINUTE, 22, DATEADD(HOUR, 11, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2023-01-29'))))
```

Without the `DATEADD` portions, the `DATETIME` datatype will add a time stamp of '00:00:00.000' automatically.

Comment: The question is for Db2

Answer (score 0):

you can add to the newly converted timestamp any hour, minutes and second you need

```
CREATE tABLE t1 (END_DT date)
```

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('29/1/2023' )
```

```
SELECT END_DT, TIMESTAMP(END_DT)  + 11 HOUR + 23 MINUTE + 53 SECOND as end_dt_with_timestamp FROM t1
```

| END_DT | END_DT_WITH_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-29 | 2023-01-29 11:23:53 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iGmoVfxB)